# Deprication plans for UntypedForm

Tags: angular, angular-material

Does anyone know if there are plans to depricate the `UntypedForm`, `UntypedFormBuilder`, etc.

I cannot find any documentation on the matter.

Comment: No, there is no deprecation plans for it. It's for creating less strict types.

Comment: If they deprecate them it'll show up here https://angular.io/guide/deprecations